# Directx 11 Constant Buffer error

Tags: c++, shader, hlsl, directx-11

When compiling my dx11 hlsl shader file, it fails, and after a bit of debugging, the error lies in this area:

```
cbuffer ConstantPointBuffer
{
    float3 dir; 
    float pad;

    float3 pos; 
    float pad;

    float3 att; 
    float pad;

    float4 ambient;
    float4 diffuse;

    float range;
    float3 pad;
}
```

But I can't think what's wrong with it...

Thank You

Comment: Is that `float pad;` from line 4 supposed to be redeclared on line 7 and 10?

Comment: Next time do better than "it fails" please. Perform debugging and obtain some useful information. This is a Q&A not a recruitment venue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple variables with the same name. Simply don't do that.

Comment: Didn't see it, but thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semicolon after the closing brace.  cbuffers are declared in the same way you would a struct or class declaration in c++.